# Can I duplicate every element of my dataset to get around some issues of small datasets?

Tags: categorical-data, small-sample, out-of-sample

Take this question with many grains of salt, because it's mostly a theoretical curiosity.

I've built a multinomial classifier using GLMnet. The problem is that some of of my input variables have an uneven distribution set values, and the dataset is quite small (around 210 observations). So when I'm building a sparse matrix with these factored variables, the (stochastically partitioned) holdout set will inevitably have fewer columns than the training set, as some factors are not represented. My solution for now has been to make the holdout set quite large (40-50% of all the data), but this seems suboptimal.

I thought one solution to this would be to duplicate every element of the dataset, which would eliminate the problem of non-representation without affecting the relative weights of data points.

However, this didn't seem to work. I still had issues with categorical values not being represented! I will eventually have access to more data for this problem, but I was just wondering a) why this didn't seem to "fool" the sparse matrices, and b) whether this is a permissible thing to do in general.

Comment: No changing the data this way changes some characteristics of the data and is like a very different sample.

Comment: How so? All of the percentages of every quantity are the same.

Comment: Larger sample size means that you have greater precision to estimate parameters.  The increased sample size is fake and you haven.t really improved anything.  The procedure is misleading and creating artificial data should never be done!

Comment: Okay, I'm not trying to fool anybody or fake any results. This is so the model has an easier time swallowing it. I'm just looking for a mathematical reason that makes it different.

Comment: How is that not what your doing if you are using fake data to fit a model?

Comment: As I said above, "Take this question with many grains of salt, because it's mostly a theoretical curiosity." I'm not publishing anything here. I'm just taking the preliminary steps in deciding on a modeling strategy and trying to work around the temporary hinderance that my dataset is small.

You said "No changing the data this way changes some characteristics of the data and is like a very different sample" I asked you to clarify what you meant by that and you haven't done so.

Comment: The sample size is a characteristic that is changed.  The sample mean and variance do not change. But this does nothing to address the small sample size issue. What do you mean by "This is so the model has an easier time swallowing it"?

Comment: As I said above, since the dataset is converted to sparse matrices when it is given as training and testing input to the model, the categorical variables are each given their own binary column. Therefore, if the dataset is small, some variables in the test set will not have all of their possible categories represented, so the test sparse matrix will not have the same number of columns as the training matrix. That is the purpose of duplicating every element.

Comment: It's clear that you can't use all those categories, start givining up on some variable which can't help you, and grouping some categories